# Application to continuously recognize popular songs on Android

Tags: android, music-recognition

I am looking for an application that **continuously** recognizes popular songs on Android, like [Shazam on iPhone](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/shazam-gets-continuous-listening-in-new-iphone-and-ipod-touch-update/). The [Android version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shazam.android) does not provide this specific feature (we have to click manually each time we hear a new track).

A description of the basic concept [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shazam_%28service%29&oldid=595438809):

> Shazam uses a mobile phone's built-in microphone to gather a brief sample of music being played. An acoustic fingerprint is created based on the sample, and is compared against a central database for a match. If a match is found, information such as the artist, song title, and album are relayed back to the user.

A solution is preferred that:

- is gratis
- has an option to send the playlist by email

Comment: 3 downvotes and no comment... if you want to help me improve the question, downvote it if that makes you feel better but at least leave a comment!

Comment: Would [MusicXMatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify) qualify? It recognises songs played from many music apps automatically.

Comment: I don't use any of those. But if you're still looking for such an app, be welcome to check with my list of apps for [Music Identification](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_identification) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Auto Shazam feature](https://support.shazam.com/hc/en-us/articles/220687408-Auto-Shazam-Android-) was [added to the Android app](https://www.shazam.com/news/auto-shazam-android) in June 8, 2016.

[image: Long press to Auto Shazam]